# How to integrate metronic themes to local formio application

Tags: metronic, formio

i have setup local instance of formio on my local machine.I am looking at integrating metronic themes to formio. And i have angular set up in my machine with angular7 version. In angular application i have metronic themes included then how to add metronic themes to formio, is there any better way to do that